# Gmail forwarded emails to a folder still show in inbox

Tags: gmail

I was able to set up Gmail  so emails from  ABC be forwarded to a folder we call D.

It does works but the problem is forwarded emails still show in the inbox like :

____D Subject of email

For example :

____D Your Bank refunded you!

Why this happens and how to get rid of these showing in the inbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Mail does not have any folders.

Instead, it has labels. 
Inbox is not a different folder but a label named `Inbox`.

When you set up your filter for emails to be "forwarded" to folder `__D`, what you actually do is to also apply label `__D` on the emails. That means that your emails now have 2 labels. `Inbox` as well as `__D`.

When you archive your emails it means that you remove the label `Inbox`.

So, in order to "take them out of" the `Inbox` and still have them show up under `__D` label, you need to edit your filter and also check the archive box.

[image]

Comment: Trying it......

Comment: Perfect! I did not have "Skip the inbox" checked. Thanks!